# Unexpected token when compiling JavaScriptServices project with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, ng-bootstrap

I am using JavaScriptServices to develop an Angular application. After adding ng-bootstrap to my project I am getting numerous 'Unexpected token' Webpack compilation errors when compiling for production (**works fine when compiling for dev**). See one of the errors below:

```
ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: D:\Data\Code\VSprod\Aerium.Velocity\src\Aerium.Velocity.Mgmt.Angular\$$_gendir\node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\alert\alert.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (13:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as i2 from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert';
| import * as i3 from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert-config';
| const styles_NgbAlert:any[] = ([] as any[]);
| export const RenderType_NgbAlert:i0.RendererType2 = i0.ɵcrt({encapsulation:2,styles:styles_NgbAlert,
|     data:{}});
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory.ts 10:0-103
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
```

Asp.Net Core 2

Node: 8.7.0

Webpack: 3.8.1

Ng-bootstrap: 1.0.0-beta.5

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                //{ test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.browser#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.server#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

If I use  ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] loaded in stead of '@ngtools/webpack' (as per the dev toolchain) everything works.

I would really appreciate some direction.

Many thanks in advance.
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on a different thread - https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1168#issuecomment-320026397
It's actually very simple, hopefully it will work for you.